# Replace generic CSS font family with custom font

Tags: css, windows, fonts, font-face, truetype

I want to replace the default font family `helvetica` in my Chrome-Browser derivate, as it's rendered in an unreadable fashion.

My replacement font-family of choice would be `"Helvetica Neue`, for which I have licensed copies.

So, inside Chrome, I use the **Stylus** plugin, and inject the following CSS into every website:

```css
@font-face
{
  font-family: helvetica;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
  src: local("Helvetica Neue");
}
```

However, using the Chrome developer tools, I can see that the **Rendered Font** property defaults back to Arial, for an element with style

```css
element.style {
    font-family: helvetica, arial, verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

Clearly, I am misunderstanding the `local(...)` argument. If, for example, I  redefine

```css
@font-face
{
  font-family: helvetica;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
  src: local("Impact");
}
```

then the changes apply (in a very ugly way). My question is thus:

**What do I specify as the argument to `local(...)` in order to actually use my local fonts?**

Additional information:

- I'm on windows, my fonts are installed OS-wide to `C:\Windows\Fonts`.
- If I drag one of the icons to a different place, I can see its filename is `HelveticaNeue.ttf`
- The same file in the font view gets displayed as `Helvetica Neue Standard`
- If I open the file in font preview, it displays the title `Helvetica Neue (OpenType)` and the font name `Helvetica Neue` (see attached screenshot)
- [image: font preview]